# can javascript object method be an action?

Tags: javascript, events, object, methods

Am a little confused about the javascript object,say I have the DOM below

```
<div class='of'></div>
<div class='of'></div>
<div class='of'></div>
<div class='of'></div>

 //select all of them 
  var fof = $('.of')
```

So fof is an array with 4 DOM object right? Can I treat the fof as javascript object ,and define some method like:

```
fof = {
  open:function(){

   }
 }
```

And is it possible to define some 'action' for fof; like click dblclick, so when the 'action' happens (like a event handler),call some method! in steady of hard coding

```
fof.click(function(){

})
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first the basics.  In Javascript, functions are first class objects.  That means that you can do:

```
var foo = function() { return 1 + 1;};
```

the same way you can do:

```
var foo = 5;
```

In Javascript, all true objects (pretty much everything except primitives) have properties.  These properties can be set to anything that a variable can be set to:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = function() { return 1 + 1; }
foo.baz = 5;
```

Whenever you see a method being used on an object, you're just seeing the function that was set as a property being run.

Since the jQuery results object (eg. `$('.of')`), which by the way is more than just an array, is a Javascript object, it can have properties, and those properties can be functions.  So you absolutely can do:

```
var fof = $('.of')
fof.foo = function() { return 1 + 1; };
fof.foo();
```

Finally, you asked about making your own jQuery-like events.  This is very easy to do using jQuery.  Here's a quick example:

```
var fakeObject = {};
fakeObject.fakeMethod = function() {
    // do something 
    $.trigger(this, 'myFakeClick');
}

var fakeObjectWatcher = {}
fakeObjectWatcher.react = function() { alert('someone did something'); };
$(fakeObject).on('myFakeClick', fakeObjectWatcher.react);

fakeObject.fakeMethod(); // triggers myFakeClick event
// fakeObjectWatcher will now alert "someone did something"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that last answer was kind of short.  I assume you are using jquery.
If not include this in your :

Attaching events is best done in your document ready section, you can put this in  too.
So this is what everything would look like.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ($'.of').click(function () {
        $(this).do something or function($this) 
    });//end click
});//end ready
```

If you want to loop through and do something to all .of's then...
    $('.of').each(function() {
        //do something
    });

Don't worry too much about the anonymous functions here, just be sure to use them.  If you want theory on what they are any google search on "anonymous functions", "lamda expressions", or "functional programming" should keep you busy for awhile.